# Mysqld and logging queries

Tags: mysql, logging

I'm seriously having problems logging queries with mysql.  I've opened my.cnf and modified a few lines, according to some online sources.  But the outcome was nil.
I've also read up on the docs at dev.mysql.com:   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

I'm obviously misunderstanding what they're trying to convey.
Here's what I'm typing into the command line:

```
service mysqld start -l mysqllogs.log
```

That didn't work.

I've opened /etc/my.cnf and added:

```
[mysqld_safe] 
log-error=/var/log/mysqld/errors.log
log=/var/log/mysqld/mysql.log 
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I even tried:

```
log-query=/var/log/mysqld/queries.log
```

So far I don't see any queries being logged.  But I do see the errors.log getting generated just fine.  I'm confused.

I don't want to edit the /etc/init.d/mysqld , kinda worried I'll mess something up.

Has anyone had this issue?  How do I turn on query logging?  (not talking about slow queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqld_safe is just shell script that invokes mysql server. So you need to add lines to [mysqld] section. Not in [mysqld_safe]

kind of

```
[mysqld]
log=/var/log/mysqld/queries.log
```

and restart mysql server after that.

Comment: You were right.  Curious, wouldn't log-error also belong there too?